# How do JavaScript cookies get sent to the browser, and how are they verified?

Tags: javascript, http, networking, cookies

I know that when cookies get sent from server to browser with a server language setting them, it happens through http or ssl or https. So where does a javascript cookie go, once the script: "document.cookie=", is executed in the browser, and through which protocol/transmission scheme?

Comment: If you're looking for how cookie are exchanged between the server and the client you can take a look at this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Implementation

Comment: this i understand, but the whole javascript cookie, is wierd, because if it gets set in the browser and not the server/host, and it uses some random logic to get set, why cant the browser just send whatever cookie it wants

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A browser simply sends *all* unexpire [HTTP cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) (not SSL related!) in its "cookie jar" which match the *domain* (and possibly *path*) of the outgoing HTTP request: **once in the "cookie jar", the cookie is sent automatically for all future requests.** Cookies sent from the server via the `Set-Cookie` header are automatically added to the "cookie jar", but, as noted, cookies can also be added from JavaScript*. In both cases the *client/browser* sends the cookie *back* to the server via the `Cookie` header.

This is why, *like all user input*, cookies should be treated with caution and *must* be backed/verified on each request for "security-sensitive" operations. Generally a [session cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_management) is used that provides this protection by being *a form* of a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) as they are (or should be) large cryptographically-sound random numbers that are never reused and are impossible predict.

The session cookie/nonce is then just a look-up into a persistent store (usually database) containing state such as the "user ID". It is a combination of the separation and nonce characteristics which prevents clients from choosing their own "user ID" based just on the value of a cookie, but...

..."security" is a complex topic, and session cookies *do not* prevent against all malicious JavaScript, such as that which employs [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) or similar, and they offer no help against man-in-the-middle attacks or eavesdropping, and are only effective against replay attacks insofar as their expiration time. Another (often overlooked) approach to verify a cookie is to use a tamper-proof verification hash, such as what ASP.NET does with view state.

A server program that blindly used/trusted `LoggedInUserId` or `IsAdministrator` cookies would be very insecurely designed indeed! :)

Happy coding.

---

*All of the *most recent* browsers support [HTTPOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) cookies, which cannot be read/overwritten by JavaScript: they can still be spoofed by other programs, however! (Some browsers only gained support as of late: e.g. Chrome 12, iOS4, Safari 5.)

Answer (score 2):

Cookies set through Javascript don't need to be transmitted: they are being set by code running within the browser, and they are also stored by the browser (as are all cookies). You can think of it as the browser writing down a reminder to itself.

Comment: @AmirRaminfar: I think you misunderstood.

Comment: but once they are stored by the browser, i assume they are then going to be used by the server/host in some way. So there is no cookie that gets really 'set', and the browser could theoretically start sending off whatever cookie value it wanted, and the host would think it was legit, so long as its the first one. Is this correct?

Comment: @SamAdams Yes, it's possible for clients to spoof cookies. This is why, like all user input, they should be treated with caution unless backed with additional *verifiable* information -- e.g. server nonce to session or tamper/replay-proof hash, etc. A server program that blindly used/trusted `LoggedInUserId` would be very poorly designed indeed!